# Deezer Radio: Track id not in radio

Tags: javascript, deezer

*How to achieve that all tracks in [Deezer Radio API](http://developers.deezer.com/api/radio/tracks) remain unchanged and therefore playable?*

**Explanation:**
I have a Deezer App (HTML+JavaScript, no external libraries) on a Set-Top-Box.

App grabs list of radio trakcs from above mentioned API. It then plays the tracks, fetching the streaming URL for each track from [streaming API](https://api.deezer.com/streaming_url.php?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&radio_id=30771&track_id=2802706&next=true).

Sometimes the list of radio tracks remains unchanged for many API calls and sometimes *the list changes with every call*. Why is this so? When a radio track is no longer in radio's list, streaming API returns an error:

```
{
    error: {
        type: "DataException",
        message: "Track id not in radio",
        code: 800
    }
}
```

For example, I get a list of 40 tracks for a particular radio, streaming API normally returns full streaming URLs but every 5th or so track fails to play (a.k.a. Deezer API throws above error) it is not because of erroneus API call but because that particular track is not in the original list of 40 tracks anymore... or this is my own assumption at least.

Therefore I am searching for a way to have a fixed list of 40 tracks that would not change until I play all 40 of them and then get the new list. Is that possible or am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways to achieve this with the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript).

1) You can directly play the radio with `DZ.player.playRadio(radio_id)`

2) If your really want a fixed list, you can fetch the track list on `http://api.deezer.com/radio/radio_id/tracks` then play all the tracks with `DZ.player.playTracks(tracks)`

Example:

```
DZ.api('/radio/30771/tracks', function(result) {
    var tracks = result.data.map(function(elem) {
        return elem.id;
    });

    DZ.player.playTracks(tracks);
});
```

**EDIT:** After discussion in the comment, the solution is just do play directly the track without mentioning the radio_id in the streaming url.

Comment: Our app does not use JS SDK, it is built ground-up in pure javascript with no html divs and css, using internal STB's player capabilities. API call looks the same as yours, without the 2.0 tag:
`var url = 'http://api.deezer.com/2.0/radio/' + _radioId + '/tracks';`

Comment: Just get the list of all the tracks with the API call once, then play all the tracks individually if you have you have your own player.

Comment: Thank you GreenLeaf, but I already do that: I get the list of all the tracks once and then playing all the tracks individually - until I get the error that track id is not in the radio (anymore?), where it was when the list was first called. Hence my original question :)

Comment: Ok then just remove the radio_id from your streaming URL : https://api.deezer.com/streaming_url.php?access_token=yourtoken&track_id=2802706&next=true and you should be fine. Btw, try not to post your access token :)

Comment: It works, thank you! Can you please post another answer so I can accept it as best? I also edited original post as you suggested.